# Event Names for WebPartZone Verbs

Tags: web-parts

Trying to figure out how to hook into some web part verb events; specifically, I want to know when the user minimizes or restores any web part, and which one.  I'm not on a sharepoint platform - strictly asp.net (4) ajax (2).

I call the following code in page load of my web part (my web part inherits UserControl and Implements IWebPart):

```
Sub test_WebPartZoneVerbEventHandlers()

    Dim i As Integer = 0

    For Each z As WebPartZone In WebPartManager.GetCurrentWebPartManager(Me.Page).Zones
        Dim restoreVerb As WebPartVerb = z.RestoreVerb
        Dim minimizeVerb As WebPartVerb = z.MinimizeVerb
        If Not IsNothing(restoreVerb) Then
            If Not IsNothing(restoreVerb.ClientClickHandler) Then
                testTextArea.InnerHtml = testTextArea.InnerHtml & i & "<br/>" & restoreVerb.ClientClickHandler
            End If

            If Not IsNothing(restoreVerb.ServerClickHandler) Then
                testTextArea.InnerHtml = testTextArea.InnerHtml & i & "<br/>" & restoreVerb.ServerClickHandler().ToString()

            End If
        End If

        If Not IsNothing(minimizeVerb) Then
            If Not IsNothing(minimizeVerb.ClientClickHandler) Then
                testTextArea.InnerHtml = testTextArea.InnerHtml & i & "<br/>" & minimizeVerb.ClientClickHandler
            End If

            If Not IsNothing(minimizeVerb.ServerClickHandler) Then
                testTextArea.InnerHtml = testTextArea.InnerHtml & i & "<br/>" & minimizeVerb.ServerClickHandler().ToString()

            End If

        End If

        i = i + 1
    Next

End Sub
```

But I don't get any names for the handlers.  Here is the output (contents of testTextArea):

```
0<br/>0<br/>1<br/>1<br/>2<br/>2<br/>0<br/>0<br/>1<br/>1<br/>2<br/>2<br/>
```

Anyone know why nothing is showing up for the client/server click handlers?

Comment: As an aside, it seems odd to me that the restore and minimize verbs are members of the web part zone, and not the web part itself, since each of the web parts have their own minimize/restore verbs that seem to operate independently...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couldn't figure out what the event names were, and frankly I'm getting fed up with UpdatePanels and thinking about getting rid of them entirely, but I was able to solve my problem by overriding the verbs property on my web part.

```
Imports ((myprojectName)).icBase
Imports System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts

''' <summary>
''' Base class for web parts.
''' </summary>
''' <remarks></remarks>
Public MustInherit Class icBaseWebPartControl
    Inherits icBaseUserControlAjax
    Implements IWebPart, IWebActionable


#Region "IWebPart Properties"

    Private _Title As String
    Private _TitleUrl As String
    Private _TitleIconImageUrl As String
    Private _Description As String
    Private _CatalogIconImageUrl As String

    Public ReadOnly Property Subtitle As String Implements IWebPart.Subtitle
        Get
            Return Nothing
        End Get
    End Property
    Public Property Title() As String Implements IWebPart.Title
        Get
            Return Me._Title
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            Me._Title = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Public Property Description() As String Implements IWebPart.Description
        Get
            Return Me._Description
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            Me._Description = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property TitleUrl() As String Implements IWebPart.TitleUrl
        Get
            Return Me._TitleUrl
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            Me._TitleUrl = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Public Property TitleIconImageUrl() As String Implements IWebPart.TitleIconImageUrl
        Get
            Return Me._TitleIconImageUrl
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            Me._TitleIconImageUrl = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property CatalogIconImageUrl() As String Implements IWebPart.CatalogIconImageUrl
        Get
            Return Me._CatalogIconImageUrl
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            Me._CatalogIconImageUrl = value
        End Set
    End Property


    ''' <summary>
    ''' Gives us some functionality of a full web part without actually extending WebPart.  (Me is only an IWebPart, not a true WebPart)
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <remarks></remarks>
    Public ReadOnly Property WebPart() As WebPart
        Get
            Dim wpm As WebPartManager = WebPartManager.GetCurrentWebPartManager(Me.Page)
            Return wpm.WebParts(Me.ID)
        End Get
    End Property

#End Region


    Public Overridable ReadOnly Property Verbs As System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.WebPartVerbCollection Implements System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.IWebActionable.Verbs
        Get

            Dim minimizeVerb As WebPartVerb = New WebPartVerb(ID & "minimizeVerb", AddressOf VerbMinimize, "OnMinimizeClicked('" & Me.ID & "')") With {.Text = "Minimize", .Description = "Minimize this web part"}
            Dim restoreVerb As WebPartVerb = New WebPartVerb(ID & "restoreVerb", AddressOf VerbRestore, "OnRestoreClicked('" & Me.ID & "')") With {.Text = "Restore", .Description = "Restore this web part"}

            Dim collection As Collection = New Collection
            Dim returnValue As New WebPartVerbCollection

            If Me.WebPart.ChromeState = PartChromeState.Minimized Then
                collection.Add(restoreVerb)
                returnValue = New WebPartVerbCollection(collection)
            End If
            If Me.WebPart.ChromeState = PartChromeState.Normal Then
                collection.Add(minimizeVerb)
                returnValue = New WebPartVerbCollection(collection)
            End If
            Return returnValue
        End Get
    End Property

    Protected Shared Sub VerbRestore(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As WebPartEventArgs)

        e.WebPart.ChromeState = PartChromeState.Normal

    End Sub

    Protected Shared Sub VerbMinimize(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As WebPartEventArgs)

        e.WebPart.ChromeState = PartChromeState.Minimized

    End Sub
End Class
```

And then I do the following in the client script called by the above:

```
 // fired when user clicks restore on  any web part 
    function OnRestoreClicked(webPartID) {
        switch (webPartID) {
            case 'ucMyTimekeeping':
                // don't need to refresh any update panels in this case, because none of the controls in timekeeping are server-side
                // (unlike files and docs, which have server-side tab containers and tabs)
                dbLoadTime();
                break;
            case 'ucMyDocuments':

                //wait a few milliseconds for the server to un-hide the web part  (see icBaseWebPartControl.vb)
                //hpTODO:  There has GOT to be a better way to do this...  maybe autopostback on the restore link, but not sure how to go about that.
                setTimeout(function () {
                    HpDocs.UpdatePanel();
                    dbLoadDocs();
                }, 200);
                break;
            case 'ucMyFiles':
                // hpTODO:  same as for ucMyDocuments
                setTimeout(function () {
                    HpFiles.UpdatePanel();
                    dbLoadFiles();
                }, 200);
                break;
            default:
                __doPostBack(webPartID, '');

        }
       //            return false;
    };
```

And here is what the UpdatePanel() functions look like:

```
// do partial postback on the update panel inside the My Files  .ascx
HpFiles.UpdatePanel = function () {
    var myFiles = $("[id$='_upMyFiles']").attr('id');
    __doPostBack(myFiles);
};
```